# Comparison test to prove $\frac{1}{p!}<\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show $\frac{1}{p!}<\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}$ for $p>2$

I notice that the right hand side of the inequality represents a geometric sequence. I can compute its infinite sum but how do I show the left hand side is smaller?

Comment: You could optionally show that $p! \gt 2^{p-1}$ as a starting point...  In either case, an induction would be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove by induction the equivalent statement $n!>2^{n-1}$ for $n>2$.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=3$:**

$3!>2^{3-1}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$n!>2^{n-1}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$(n+1)!=n!\cdot(n+1)>\color{red}{n!}\cdot2>\color{red}{2^{n-1}}\cdot2=2^n$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 2):

Computing the geometric sum $\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{p-1}}$ is irrelevant to proving this inequality. Note that it is equivalent to proving $$2^{p-1}<p!$$ for $p>2$. You should prove this inequality with induction. The base case of $p=3$ should be straightforward. For the induction step, you can multiply the inequality  $2^{k-1}<k!$ by $2$, and then use the fact that $2<k+1$ to quickly see that $2^k< (k+1)!$. Once you've done that, you know the inequality will hold for all $k \in \Bbb{N}$ where $k>3$, and you can flip the inequality back to get the result you are after.

Comment: Could I have not showed that the left hand side approaches 0 as P goes to infinity? Then this means it would approach zero. So 0 would be less than the geometric series which converges to a finite number?

Comment: @User69127 no, because there is no series; we are dealing with a sequence. It is true that $\frac{1}{p!}$ converges to $0$ as $p \to \infty$ but it is also true that $\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}$ converges to $0$ as $p \to \infty$. So showing they both converge to zero would only establish that the *limits* are equal, not that for any given integer $p>2$, one term is less than the other. Not sure where you are getting this idea for a series, but for a given $p$, it always true that $$\frac{1}{2^{p-1}} \neq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} + \ldots = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

hint: $2^{p-1} = 2\cdot 2\cdots2 < 2\cdot 3\cdot (2\cdot 2) \cdot 5\cdot 6\cdots p$