# How would you prove that $2^{n-1} > n!$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

How do i prove that $2^{n-1} < n!$ for all $n \ge 1$

This is my proof:

Base case:
Let n=1 then $2^{1-1} =1$ is the same on the right side so it holds

Inductive step:
let $k \le 1$ we assume that the proposition holds for n=K

i know i want to show that $2^n < (n+1)!$

then i have $2^{n-1}= 2^n\times2^{-1} < n! \times 2^-1$ by inductive hypothesis but then i get stuck here.

Comment: sorry for the typo, its suppose to be $\ge$

Comment: In your base case you find equality, which is not allowed, so it fails.

Comment: [There you go](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1194492/131263). Somebody asked an equivalent question here about an hour ago.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to up-vote it if it answers your question :)

Comment: just did =D @barakmanos

Comment: Up-vote the answer, not the comment :)

Answer (score 6):

$$n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n\ge 1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdots 2=2^{n-1}$$ and the inequality is strict for $n\ge 3$. So actually the opposite of your inequality holds.

Comment: so i should have had 3 base cases

Comment: i always thought you had to start the work from the left side and somehow conclude that it holds for n+1

Comment: im sorry you are right i must have made a typo so does that mean if we prove by induction n!> $2^{n-1}$ should be enough since it is the same thing

Answer (score 2):

I think induction is an overly formal strategy here. The number $n!$ is a product of $n-1$ positive integers, each at least two. The number $2^{n-1}$ is also a product of $n-1$ positive integers, all of which are exactly two.