# Prove by the method of finite induction

Tags: induction

Using the method of finite induction show that $2^{(n-1)} \leq n! \forall n$ belong to $N$ (Natural Number)
Can someone please prove this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you prove that $2^{n-1} &gt; n!$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194619/how-would-you-prove-that-2n-1-n)

Comment: See [principle of finite induction](http://planetmath.org/principleoffiniteinduction).

Comment: Welcome to the site. We don't want to do your homework for you, please tell us what you have tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: Base case : $n=1$; thus : $2^{(1-1)} \le 1!$

Comment: @Henrik I can't upload the picture

Comment: @ScienceFreak Count this question as a "live and learn" experience. That is, be sure, if you plan to post in the future, to include some context in the question: Where did you encounter this problem.?  What have you tried?  Where, exactly, are you stuck?, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=0$ and $1$, it is true.

let $n\geq 1$ such that

$2^{n-1}\leq n!$.

$\implies$

$2^n=2.2^{n-1}\leq 2.n!\leq (n+1).n!$

$\implies$

$2^n\leq (n+1)!$.

thus

$\forall n \in \mathbb N \;\; 2^n\leq n!$.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. This really helped! :D